# Longest common subsequence using recursion

Tags: c++, recursion, functional-programming, dynamic-programming

Basically I was trying to solve [longest common subsequence problem](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/longest-common-substring1452/1#) using recursion. in one of the site i was supposed to write the function which had below form;

```
int longestCommonSubstr (string S1, string S2, int n, int m)
{
    // your code here
}
```

I can write recursive code of it as additional parameter `n` and `m` are given. where `n and m` are length of string S1, S2 respectively. Another site asked me to solve same question but without providing `n` and `m` which is shown below;

```
int longestCommonSubstr (string S1, string S2)
{
    // your code here
}
```

For the first site my complete recursive function looks like below;

```
int longestCommonSubstr (string S1, string S2, int n, int m)
{
    // your code here
    if(n==0 || m==0){
        return 0;
    }
    if(S1[n-1]==S2[m-1]){
        return 1+longestCommonSubstr(S1,S2,n-1,m-1);
    }
    else{
        return max(longestCommonSubstr(S1,S2,n-1,m),longestCommonSubstr(S1,S2,n,m-1));
    }
}
```

**But i am unable to write recursive code when we are not allowed to use parameter `n` and `m` as that of second case.** kindly looking for help to approach the recursive code for the second case.

Comment: what is your question? "I find it difficult... " is not a question

Comment: There are n ways to rotate one of the string, then it becomes longest common prefix, which is trivial to do in `O(m)`. Thus `O(n*m)` is also proven.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number sir i meant i'm unable to write recursive code for the second case and looking and curious to know about any such approach.

Comment: You do realize that functions can call other functions, right? I would also note that you likely won't want the recursive solution (you won't hit the time complexity), but you'll want to continue to develop it into a bottom up solution. This is a dynamic programming exercise, not (just) a recursion exercise.

Comment: Also, the site limits itself to g++ 5.4? That's ludicrously out of date. You also can't copy/paste out of their editor window.

Answer (score 0):

You are completely able to use your recursive solution if you want. Functions can call other functions, after all. Just calculate them and pass them to your recursive function.

But that's only partially helping. Even on geeks for geeks (a horrible site, by the way), the time complexity requirement is O(n*m), which recursion won't meet.

This is not just a recursion exercise, but a dynamic programming exercise. The recursive solution is generally considered the "brute force" solution due to it typically having to solve identical sub-problems repeatedly.

You could help yourself by memoizing the sub-solutions (also called the top-down approach) you've already encountered, but you're still making approximately three recursive calls per iteration.

You need to take it further, and derive a bottom-up solution.

We'll create a 2D array. The rows will be the characters of `S1`, and the columns will be the rows of `S2`. We will add an extra row and column to the beginning to represent the *other* string being empty.

So, given: `S1 = "ABCDGH";` and `S2 = "ACDGHR;"`, we start with an array I will call `counts`:

```
  0 A C D G H R

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

A 0

B 0

C 0

D 0

G 0

H 0
```

We can then make direct character-to-character comparisons. If `S1[i] == S2[j]`, we add `1` to the value at `counts[i - 1][j - 1]`. This is how we track our substring lengths. We will keep a value of the maximum length, and anytime we find two matching characters, we'll update our maximum length as needed.

If `S1[i] != S2[j]`, we simply store `0` in `counts[i][j]`. By the time we've filled out the entire 2D array, we know the maximum. No recursion needed.

Here's what the filled out array looks like:

```
  0 A C D G H R

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

A 0 1 0 0 0 0 0

B 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

C 0 0 1 0 0 0 0

D 0 0 0 2 0 0 0

G 0 0 0 0 3 0 0

H 0 0 0 0 0 4 0
```

And this is the code:

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
  std::vector<std::vector<int>> substrCounts(S1.length() + 1,
                                             std::vector<int>(S2.length() + 1));
  int maxCount = 0;

  for (std::size_t rowIdx = 1; rowIdx < substrCounts.size(); ++rowIdx) {
    for (std::size_t columnIdx = 1; columnIdx < substrCounts[0].size();
         ++columnIdx) {
      if (S1[rowIdx - 1] == S2[columnIdx - 1]) {
        substrCounts[rowIdx][columnIdx] =
            substrCounts[rowIdx - 1][columnIdx - 1] + 1;
        maxCount = std::max(maxCount, substrCounts[rowIdx][columnIdx]);
      } else {
        substrCounts[rowIdx][columnIdx] = 0;
      }
    }
  }

  return maxCount;  
  }
};
```

It passed all 119 test cases on geeks for geeks and they counted the run-time at 0.05 seconds. You'll also note that I don't bother with `n` or `m` at all; they're not needed.

I would normally just change the signature, but the site doesn't allow it. I should have then cast the unused parameters to `void`, but the site doesn't run with any warnings at all, allowing you write the most god-awful code you can imagine. I didn't bother with the casts only because I was feeling just that lazy and harping on about best practices when you have `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` and `using namespace std;` forced on you is pointless.